# The dimension of $H_{n} $ ,the space of all $ n \times n $ matrices, as a vector space over $ \mathbb{R} $ , is

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ n $ be a positive integer and let $ H_{n} $  be the space of all  $ n \times n $  matrices
$ A = (a_{ij}) $ with entries in $ \mathbb{R} $ satisfying $  a_{ij} = a_{rs} $ whenever $ i + j = r + s \,\, (i,j,r,s=1,2,\dots,n)$ . Then the dimension of  $ H_{n} $ , as a vector space over $ \mathbb{R} $ , is

$ 1. \quad n^{2}  \hspace{50pt} 2.\quad n^{2}-n+1  \hspace{50pt} 3. \quad 2n+1   \hspace{50pt} 4.\quad  2n-1 $

I am trying to solve it by taking $ n=3 $ for generalized form of matrix and found

M=  \begin{pmatrix} 
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} 
\end{pmatrix}

where  $ a_{12} = a_{21} $ , $ a_{13} = a_{31}= a_{22} $ , $ a_{23} = a_{32} $
 Now I can't understand how to conclude it?

Can I conclude it as follows:
Since the matrix has $ 5 $ non-trivial distinct elements, so the dimension of  $ H_{n} $ is $ 5 $ and as $ 5= 2 * 3 -1 $ so the answer is $ 2n -1 $ ?
Any help in this regard really appreciated.

Comment: I'd count it for $n=2,3$.

Comment: How many equivalence classes $(i,j)$ are there?

Comment: Why don't you try with some small examples? Look at $n = 2$, write some matrices down and see if you can guess a basis.

Comment: Regarding your edit, making a conclusion from a single exemple is really dangerous, I almost concluded that the answer was $n^2-n+1$ because it was correct for $n=1,2$.

Comment: I am trying to solve it by taking n = 3 for generalized form and found
M =
a11 a12 a13
a21 a22 a23
a31 a32 a33

where a12 = a21 , a13 = a31 = a22 , a23 = a32 Now I can't understand how to conclude it?
Can I conclude it as follows: Since the matrix has 5 non-trivial distinct elements,
so the dimension of H_n is 5 and as 5 = 2 * 3 - 1 so ant answer is 2n - 1 ?

Comment: But I found the given answer is  (2n-1)

Comment: That's what I'm trying to say, you found the answer based on an exemple, if you're not careful enough, you may be wrong, and the answer can work out ONLY for that exemple. Anyway, you were right on this one, I'll try to write an answer to explain why.

Comment: What result you find ? @Berci

Answer (score 1):

Consider the diagonals of the matrix going form lower left to upper right. All the entries in those diagonals are of the form $a_{ij}$, where i+j=k for some fixed k. Count the number of such diagonals and those are the equivalence classes of entries.

Comment: Is it the general rules for finding dimension of the such kind of  vector space? If it happens, then please mention the proper reference. Thank you.

Comment: The general rule is to find the number of degrees of freedom you have. In this case, once you found a$_{ij}$, the entries on the same upper diagonal were determined.